# A warning message when running R program

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  无法载入共享目标对象‘/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so’：:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3: symbol __netf2, version GCC_4.3.0 not defined in file libgcc_s.so.1 with link time reference
在启动过程中 - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

When I firstly install R, it works and shows no warning message.
I can only fix this problem by using *sudo R* to run R program. And I tried to create a environment variable DLLpath as the error says, but it did not work.
How can I fix this?